# Why do I get 'Dead code following this construct' with the following code?

Tags: scala

I have following scala code

```
def message(attachmentId: UUID) : URI = {
  var r : mutable.MutableList[BasicTemplate] = new mutable.MutableList[BasicTemplate]
  val t : Type = new TypeToken[Iterable[BasicTemplate]](){}.getType()
  val m : String = "[{\"basicTemplate\":\"TEMPLATE\",\"baseline\":\"DEMO\",\"identifier\":\"0599999999\"}]"

  r = new Gson().fromJson(m, t)
  Console.println(r.head.getBasicTemplateName)

  URI.create("http://google.com")
}
```

And it gives me following compilation error:

```
[ERROR] Class1.scala:402: error: dead code following this construct
[ERROR] r = new Gson().fromJson(m, t)
```

Any ideas why I get this error are highly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to specify the type after declaring variables.

Comment: May be it is caused by the 'r' re-assignment. More info - https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6339

Comment: I don't know your error, but you create a list in line "var r ... = new ..., then you throw that list away in line r = new Gson(). Why don't you use val r = new Gson()...

Comment: @wheaties: I've tried to remove types and it didn't help

Comment: @Arne: I've also tried to use val r = new Gson().. and it still gives the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: @AVE sorry no further ideas never had that problem

Comment: @fiction: Note that the diagnostic in https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6339 is a warning but the one shown in this question is an error (a lot harder to ignore…)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Look at the [signature](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader,%20java.lang.reflect.Type%29) of `fromJson`:

```
public <T> T fromJson(String json, Type typeOfT)
```

As you can see, this method has type parameter `T`, but you called it without specifying it. This way, type inferencer understood it as `new Gson().fromJson[Nothing](m, t)` and the entire expression was assigned the type `Nothing`.

In Scala, `Nothing` is a bottom type that is a subtype of all types and has no values. Methods that return `Nothing` are guaranteed to never return, either because they always throw an exception, fall into infinite loop, forcibly terminate the program (e.g. `sys.exit()`), etc. In your case, the `fromJson` call will cause a `ClassCastException` to be thrown when the JVM tries to cast its result to `Nothing`. Therefore, everything after that call is a dead code.

This type inference behaviour is different from Java, which would normally infer `new Gson().<Object>fromJson(m, t)` here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, I'm very new to Scala, could you please suggest what is the correct way of calling this fromJson method in Scala?
I thought Scala should understand that the return type should be the same as type of variable 'r'

Comment: @AVE I guess you need to specify your type explicitly: `new Gson().fromJson[mutable.MutableList[BasicTemplate]](m, t)`

Comment: @AVE Although I must admit that the more I think about this, the more I'm starting to suspect that it's a bug.

Comment: @AVE The Java method is generic. In Java code, it is typically inferred from the type of the variable to which the result is assigned. The alternative is to do `gsonVar.<SomeType>fromJson(..)`. Otherwise there is nothing else in the method that can help to infer the type. The same is true for Scala. Since `r` doesn't have a type declaration, nothing can be inferred.

Comment: Oh right, So I still don't get it. Can the type argument not be inferred from that type in Scala?

Comment: @ghik Sorry for the late post, but I just wanted to correct something in your answer. `Nothing` is actually a valid, required return type for any function that never returns, as well as being the type of a `throw` expression. (For example, `scala.sys.exit()` returns `Nothing`.) If a function doesn't return, then anything that follows a call to it will never execute, hence it is dead code. Your comment that _the compiler thinks that your assignment will always throw an exception_ is not actually correct.

Comment: Very helpful answer, but the Scala error message is not very helpful in this case. Should the message have said "Missing type in function call"  or somewhere along that line, I could have fixed the issue right away.